# openpyxl - increment of x and y axis ticks

Tags: python, excel, charts, openpyxl

The bar chart I'm creating is auto scaling the Y axis tick increments starting at 0 as `0, .5, 1, 1.5` etc. I would like to have it increment in only whole numbers, ie `0, 1, 2, 3, 4` etc. I've tried `chart.y_axis.tickLblSkip = 1` but had my doubts because I believe this is just the label itself, not the actual tick marks. Is there a way to control this? I see in the documentation you can control the overall scale of the axis with `chart.y_axis.scaling.min` and `max` but this isn't what I'm looking for.

Below is the code used to generate my chart. Below that is the chart itself where you can see the Y axis ticks, because 'unique jobs' will only be a whole number, it looks stupid to have decimals:

```
# Unique jobs chart
chart = BarChart()
chart.type = 'col'
chart.style = 13
chart.title = 'Unique Job Numbers Run'
chart.y_axis.title = 'Total Number of Parts'
chart.x_axis.title = 'Machine Number'
chart.legend = None
data = Reference(yearly_machine_totals_ws, min_col=4, min_row=1,
                 max_row=yearly_machine_totals_ws.max_row, max_col=4)
cats = Reference(yearly_machine_totals_ws, min_col=1, min_row=2,
                 max_row=yearly_machine_totals_ws.max_row)
chart.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)
chart.set_categories(cats)
chart_ws.add_chart(chart, 'L2')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your chart's `y_axis` is of type `NumericAxis`. To achieve what you want you will need to define its `majorUnit` property:

```
chart.y_axis.majorUnit = 1
```

**How do you know which properties are available for a certain type of chart or axis?** 
You'll need to figure out what's implemented. Your chart is of type `BarChart`. Inspecting the [documentation on BarChart](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.chart.bar_chart.html) yields that its x axis is of type `TextAxis`, whereas the y axis is a `NumericAxis`. The features of all axis types are documented [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.chart.axis.html). Apparently, the `tickLblSkip` property is only present in `TextAxis` and `SeriesAxis`. For `NumericAxis` you will need the `unit` property, probably `min` and `max` might be useful, too.

An easy, interactive way to determine any object's type is the `type()` method. Putting

```
print(type(chart.y_axis))
```

in your code will conveniently reveal:

```
<class 'openpyxl.chart.axis.NumericAxis'>
```

Comment: That was close, what I actually needed was `chart.y_axis.majorUnit = 1`. You did however point me in the right direction, I did not know about `NumericAxis`, or that I could check it with `type`. This helped to find what I need in the documentation. Adjust your answer and I will accept it. Thank you!