# Python openpyxl 3.0.6 add_chart is making Excel xlsx corrupt

Tags: excel, openpyxl

Using openpyxl 3.0.6 to make a sheet and everything is fine until the code adds a chart to the sheet.  When I comment out `this_sheet.add_chart(chart, cell_loc)` the workbook will open no problem but without the chart.   LibreOffice Calc will open the workbook without any problem. Has anyone else had to deal with this or is there something wrong with the chart code?

I have looked at  [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59308064/openpyxl-workbook-save-function-creates-a-corrupt-and-un-openable-excel-xlsx) but this does not seem to be my issue.

```
chart = LineChart()
chart.smooth = False

chart.title = "Change From 2017"
chart.style = 12
chart.y_axis.title = "Delta"
chart.y_axis.crossAx = 500
chart.x_axis = TextAxis(crossAx=100) 

chart.y_axis.scaling.min = 0.00
chart.y_axis.scaling.max = 0.12

chart.legend = None
chart.x_axis.delete = False
chart.y_axis.delete = False
#chart.title.delete = False

chart.add_data(data, from_rows=True)
chart.set_categories(cats)
s1 = chart.series[0]
s1.smooth = False
s1.marker.symbol = "triangle"
s1.marker.graphicalProperties.solidFill = "FF0000" # Marker filling
s1.marker.graphicalProperties.line.solidFill = "FF0000" # Marker outline
s1.graphicalProperties.line.noFill = True

cell_loc = str("B"+ str(this_sheet.max_row+5))
chart.height = 12 # default is 7.5
chart.width = 65 # default is 15
this_sheet.add_chart(chart, cell_loc)
```

When Excel does "recover" the file there is no chart and has a Repair report -

> Removed Part: /xl/drawings/drawing5.xml part.  (Drawing shape) 
> error182120_03.xmlErrors were detected in file 'D:\01_SSI_Projects\2020_Projects\20247\resave_report.xlsx'Removed Part: /xl/drawings/drawing1.xml part.  (Drawing shape)Removed Part: /xl/drawings/drawing2.xml part.  (Drawing shape)Removed Part: /xl/drawings/drawing3.xml part.  (Drawing shape)Removed Part: /xl/drawings/drawing4.xml part.  (Drawing shape)Removed Part: /xl/drawings/drawing5.xml part.  (Drawing shape)

**UPDATE**
I commented out 1 line:

```
#chart.y_axis.crossAx = 500
```

Excel no longer gives an error.  The data type in the y_axis is NumericAxis so that was the problem. This comes from [increment of x and y axis ticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59304386/openpyxl-increment-of-x-and-y-axis-ticks)

Comment: If you think there is a bug in some software the best thing to do is to submit a bug report.

Comment: Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/2385133/charlie-clark   I tested the sample code at https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/charts/line.html and this worked fine.